# Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I came across a problem in an online course:

Write a function called vowelCount which accepts a string and returns an object with the keys as the vowel and the values as the number of times the vowel appears in the string. This function should be case insensitive so a lowercase letter and uppercase letter should count

Examples:
    vowelCount('Elie') // {e:2,i:1};

the solution from the instructor came like this:

```
function vowelCount(str){
    var splitArr = str.toLowerCase().split("");
    var obj = {};
    var vowels = "aeiou";

    splitArr.forEach(function(letter){
        if(vowels.indexOf(letter) !== -1){
            if(obj[letter]){
                obj[letter]++;
            } else{
                obj[letter] = 1;
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

I understand the solution until the second "if" statement. I know that the first "if" statement is to check if the "letters" in the input string belongs to the "vowels". Then in the second "if" it is checking if the "letter is in the empty "obj" object created above, but at that line, the "obj" is empty bofore the "letter" is added to it, so what is the point for that "if". Also, why does adding this new "letter" to the object require an increment. I tried the code without increment and the object is still empty.

Comment: The `if` part does the "we've found one vowel `letter` so we increment its counter", the `else` part is the "we've found a vowel which is not yet in `obj` so we add it with a counter of `1`

Comment: After `obj[letter] = 1` is executed, if that same letter is encountered again, then the `if(obj[letter])` check will pass. `obj` only starts as the empty object, the purpose of the `forEach` loop is to gradually populate it with the correct information, so that it can be returned at the end.

Comment: Just FWIW, while still entirely valid, that's fairly old-style JavaScript code (circa the ES5 standard, 2009). ES2015 added several features you'd use to solve this problem today.

Comment: it just checks if it's already there, to create a object node... otherwise you wouldn't be able to do ++, as it would be undefined

Comment: Thank you I finally got it. I forgot that forEach is a loop and checking individual letter every turn. I just started learning javascript so that is why the course is teaching the old style I think, later on in the course will be about ES15 16 and 17.

Comment: I really don't think that @T.J.Crowder is right about his opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's checking if you've ever seen the letter before in the loop. If you've never written to `obj[letter]`, then when you do `obj[letter]`, you get back the value `undefined`, which is falsy (treated as `false` by things like an `if`). `if(obj[letter])` is checking for a *truthy* value (a value that isn't falsy) so that it adds to the number already stored at `obj[letter]` if it's there (`obj[letter]++`). But when it sees a falsy value like `undefined`, it takes the `else` branch and sets `obj[letter]` to `1` because the code knows that `letter` hasn't been seen before.

---

Just FWIW, while still entirely valid, that's fairly old-style JavaScript code (circa the ES5 standard, 2009). ES2015 added several features you'd use to solve this problem today:

```
function vowelCount(str){
    // Use a Map to remember how many of each ltter you've
    // seen. You could use an object as well, but ideally you'd
    // create the object with out a prototype to avoid having
    // any conflict with inherited properties from `Object.prototype`.
    const counts = new Map(); // const counts = Object.create(null);

    // The set of vowels
    const vowels = new Set("aeiou");

    // Loop through the letters
    for (const letter of str) {
        // If it's not a vowel...
        if (!vowels.has(letter)){
            // Count it
            const currentCount = counts.get(letter) || 0;
            counts.set(letter, currentCount + 1);
            // Or using an object:
            // const currentCount = counts[letter] || 0;
            // counts[letter] = currentCount + 1;
        }
    });
    return counts;
}
```

Comment: That function could be refactored to a one-liner too.

Comment: old style coding doesn't change the result, not really a fine answer; especially when it's for learning purposes

Comment: @FlashThunder What's the problem here? T.J. explained the original code in detail and then added a modern version of it.

Comment: no problem, just don't agree with a statement that old style coding is bad for beginners with programming at all

Comment: @FlashThunder - I didn't say it was; I was just introducing the OP to the newer structures. I don't know what you mean by "change the result"...?

Comment: @RoboRobok - Yes -- at the cost of clarity for the beginner.

Comment: does it really matter? the output is the same, and it wasn't an exercise to do the best what you got, but to learn something... i got no problem with your answer, was just a comment, don't take it personally; I got lots of students that don't understand the basics and the way the professor went was ok for me

Answer (score 0):

We can use regular expression to match vowels in a sentence.

**Regular expression to match all occurrence of vowel in a string:*/[aeiouAEIOU]+?/g***

> Below is the working code snippet:

```
    //function that takes string as input
    //function returns an object containing vowel count without case in account.
    function vowelCount(input) {
        //to get vowel count using string.match
        var arrVowels =input.match(/[aeiouAEIOU]+?/g);

        //acc=accumulator, curr=current value
        return arrVowels.reduce(function (acc, curr) {

           if (typeof acc[curr.toLowerCase()] == 'undefined') {
               acc[curr.toLowerCase()] = 1;
           } 
           else {
               acc[curr.toLowerCase()] += 1;
           }
           return acc;

           // the blank object below is default value of the acc (accumulator)
           }, {});           
      }
```